# Follow up question answered by Bhushan Kawadkar - Please explain

Tags: javascript, datatable, duplicates

[How to display duplicate rows in same color using datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831225/how-to-display-duplicate-rows-in-same-color-using-datatable)

Please I need some explanation on this answer. I tried this solution and it applies the color to all rows cause I have one column multiple times, which is ok, but I need to check two columns as a tuple. For example, (using the original question) if I have "Black Winters - Project Engineer" and "Black Winters - System Architect" I don't need to color it cause it is correct for me, disregarding the rest of the columns on the table. But I can not have this 2 specifics columns duplicated. I tried to modify the duplicateRowMap but didn't work. Can someone explain it please, or share a reference to the definition of this type of solution. How can I modify it? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can filter using the javascript ```filter``` function on arrays and filter out the values that you want to be the same in some order and then apply the same color in the form of ```CSS``` to the datatable. The answer is simple and is possible to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is another type of solution, to put it in two arrays. 
I was expecting an explanation of this 
"var value = duplicateRowMap[name];
       if(value!='x'){"
Do you know what does it do? Where does the x comes from? And how are they assigned to the value variable?

Comment: How is duplicateRowMap getting its values?

Comment: You asked "_Where does `X` come from?_". It comes from here: `duplicateRowMap[data.name] = 'X';`. I found it by searching for the letter `X` in the code provided in the answer. So, now you can investigate the logic used which determines when `X` is assigned - and that will help you to understand what `X` means. I recommend using  your browser's debugger and its console, together with `console.log()` statements to get a better understanding of what the code is doing. I think that will help you a lot. You will then also see how `duplicateRowMap` is populated, and so on... This will help a lot.

Comment: You can also take a look at [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), which is full of excellent advice along the same (and better) lines.