# How to read this arrow function as legacy style?

Tags: javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831844/6719857

```
  var data = [{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$3,120"
  }, {
    "name": "Black Winters",
    "position": "Project Engineer",
    "salary": "$1,300"
  }, {
    "name": "Black Winters",
    "position": "Project Engineer",
    "salary": "$1,300"
  }].map((o,i,arr)=>{
    o.color = arr.filter(({name})=>name===o.name).length>1 ?'orange':'red';
    return o;
  });
```

I'm particularly interested in the following parts

```
arr.filter(({name})=>name===o.name).length>1 ?'orange':'red';
```

I want to implement it without using the arrow function, without without compiling.

Because I need to support legacy browsers like IE11.

Anyone help?

Comment: Paste it in https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Have you checked MDN documentation of [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? There are examples of usage with function expressions.

Comment: `function ( {name} ) { return name === o.name } )`.  The `{name}` has nothing to do with arrow functions, it's deconstructing the object that's passed in as the 1st parameter of the filter function and extracting just `name`

Comment: Instead of manually changing your code to not use arrow functions or deconstructing, I would still suggest to utilize a transpiler like Babel that converts the code in the deployment step.

Comment: @t.niese I think the OP means "and without transpiling" by "without without compiling"

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes i think so too. But I still would suggest to use a transpiler. There are various problem with inconsistencies in older IE so I would always suggest to use a transpiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code uses arrow functions and destructuring, both of which are not supported by IE11.
See https://caniuse.com/?search=destructure and https://caniuse.com/?search=arrow

This should work:

```js
  var data = [{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$3,120"
  }, {
    "name": "Black Winters",
    "position": "Project Engineer",
    "salary": "$1,300"
  }, {
    "name": "Black Winters",
    "position": "Project Engineer",
    "salary": "$1,300"
  }].map(function(o,i,arr) {
    o.color = arr.filter(function(elem) { return elem.name===o.name }).length>1 ?'orange':'red';
    return (o);
  });
  console.log(data)
```

Here's another way of doing it would be closer to `O(n)`.  The `saw` collection is literally discarded - it's only there to record if a name already appeared, it's included for clarity

```js
var data = [ {"name": "Tiger Nixon","position": "System Architect","salary": "$3,120"}
           , {"name": "Black Winters","position": "Project Engineer","salary": "$1,300"}
           , {"name": "Black Winters","position": "Project Engineer","salary": "$1,300"}
           ]
let saw = data.reduce(function(saw, current) {
  // Set the color of the current element depending on whether the
  // name has already been seen and then record the fact that the
  // name has now been seen
  if (saw[current.name]) {
    saw[current.name].color = current.color = 'orange'
  } else {
    current.color = 'red'
    saw[current.name] = current
  }
  return saw
}, {});
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

All your arrow function is it checks if there is more than one `name` exist on the object then it adds a new property on respective object with value `orange` else `red`

```
arr.filter(({ name }) => name === o.name).length > 1 ? "orange" : "red";
```

So you can make it more efficient if you create a `dict` and then add the count of all object's `name` property and then map over the source array and add the `color` property according to the count that is stored in the `dict` object.

OLD CODE

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Tiger Nixon",
    position: "System Architect",
    salary: "$3,120",
  },
  {
    name: "Black Winters",
    position: "Project Engineer",
    salary: "$1,300",
  },
  {
    name: "Black Winters",
    position: "Project Engineer",
    salary: "$1,300",
  },
];

const result = data.map((o, i, arr) => {
  o.color =
    arr.filter(({
      name
    }) => name === o.name).length > 1 ? "orange" : "red";
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Tiger Nixon",
    position: "System Architect",
    salary: "$3,120",
  },
  {
    name: "Black Winters",
    position: "Project Engineer",
    salary: "$1,300",
  },
  {
    name: "Black Winters",
    position: "Project Engineer",
    salary: "$1,300",
  },
];

var dict = {};
data.forEach(function(o) {
  if (dict[o.name]) ++dict[o.name];
  else dict[o.name] = 1;
});


var result = data.map(function(o, i) {
  if (dict[o.name] === 1) o.color = "red";
  else o.color = "orange";

  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

---